# Azure Data Factory DataFlow error : Temporary failure in name resolution

Tags: azure-data-factory

We are getting error in Azure Data Factory Data Flow using Azure Hosted Integration runtime and Private Link linked to Private Link Service and the target is SQL Server behind load balancers.

> Job failed due to reason: java.lang.Throwable: DataFlowManagerClient.getPayload fail to getPayload request for run:90e9cb52-f2ba-48fb-ba9f-2a5de66454ab, exception:java.net.UnknownHostException: dmeus2aksig1aks.svc.datafactory.azure.com: Temporary failure in name resolution

What could cause this?

Comment: Please provide a few things:

1. Is this error consistent or transient? Is it still happening now?

2. What are the timeout and retry settings?

-- Have you tried adjusting these to resolve the error? (I suggest you set a long timeout for this)
3. What type of spark cluster is the flow using?
-- Was it working prior, did you make any changes that lead to this?
-- What is the source?
4. Is this the whole error message or are there more details?

Answer (score 0):

I'm experiencing the same issue where my pipeline is failing intermittently at any step of the flow or pipeline. This happens randomly and is not related to the timeout I've set. I haven't made any changes to the flow or pipelines, and I'm seeing this issue occur in multiple pipelines daily, although sometimes it happens in just one. The only solution I've found is to re-run the pipeline, which resolves the issue temporarily. I'm looking for advice on how to troubleshoot and fix this issue permanently.